# make the ELSE of one CASE WHEN equal to another CASE in the same SELECT clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery, case

How do I make the ELSE of one CASE WHEN equal to another CASE in the same SELECT clause?

In this example, the ELSE 0 under Cost equal to the Revenue. If the Cost is 0 use the Revenue value from above.

```
SELECT
    subselect.item,
    SUM(subselect.Revenue)
    SUM(subselect.Cost)
FROM(
    Select
        item,
        item_price,
        quantity,
        Item_cost,
        SUM(CASE  
            WHEN (item in ('1','2','3'))
            THEN item_price * quantity
            ELSE 0
            END) AS REVENUE,
        SUM(CASE  
            WHEN (item in ('1','2','3'))
            THEN item_cost * quantity
            ELSE 0
            END) AS COST
    ) AS subselect
...
```

Revenue:

| item | item price | quantity | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 6 |

Cost:

| item | item cost | quantity | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Since the Cost is 0, use the Revenue for the item, in this case 6.

I am using PL SQL Developer against an Oracle database.

Comment: Yes it is possible, and your syntax looks largely correct.

Comment: I am trying to get to this 

ELSE REVENUE
END) as Cost

instead of the 0 in the question sql

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using, and share some simple data and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

From your data provided it looks like you don't need subselect at all since you could check the total cost with Case expression and choose what to select - COST or REVENUE.

```sql
WITH    -- S a m p l e   D a t a :
    revenue (ITEM, ITEM_PRICE, QUANTITY, REVENUE)  AS
        ( Select 1, 1, 2, 2 From Dual UNION All
          Select 2, 3, 1, 6 From Dual UNION All
          Select 3, 2, 3, 6 From Dual ),
    cost (ITEM, ITEM_PRICE, QUANTITY, ITEM_COST)  AS
        ( Select 3, 2, 0, 0 From Dual )
```

```sql
--     M a i n   S Q L :
Select      r.ITEM,
            SUM(r.ITEM_PRICE * r.QUANTITY) AS REVENUE,
            Case When  SUM(c.ITEM_COST * c.QUANTITY) = 0
                 Then  SUM(r.ITEM_PRICE * r.QUANTITY)
            Else SUM(c.ITEM_COST * c.QUANTITY)
            End AS COST
From        revenue r 
Inner Join  cost c ON(c.ITEM = r.ITEM)
Group By    r.ITEM
```

```sql
/*  R e s u l t :
      ITEM    REVENUE       COST
---------- ---------- ----------
         3          6          6    */
```